# How can I setup a firewall with whitelisted IPs for my heroku app?

Tags: heroku, firewall

I have a heroku app and I would like to configure the firewall on it to allow connections from only some whitelisted IPs. I know heroku dynos run ubuntu. So is there anyway to configure ufw on it? Or can I configure the pre-existing firewall?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Heroku don't provide any facility to do that. If you want to achieve something similar you would have to do it in the code of your application.

Comment: Aah, that sucks. It won't be the same at application level :(